# how to decrease the width of input type in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written a code for a form , but I want to decrease the width with out damaging the layout and I'm unable to change the width of input fields.

while decreasing the size labels are getting misaligned

```
<head>
   <title>Add Customer</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container" style="color:green">
         <h2 align="center" style="color: blue">Add Customer</h2>
         <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="CustomerName">Name:</label>
               <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" width ="511px">-->
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Customer Name" width ="511px">    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="email">Email:</label>
               <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
               <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="pwd">Company:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Company Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="pwd">Comment:</label>
               <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Enter Comments"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: try to add width with display:block; property

Comment: if you want to give custom width to input fields then remove form-control class and give custom css. see here http://jsfiddle.net/Leo_the_lion/Lqsrw039/1/ or see this http://jsfiddle.net/Leo_the_lion/Lqsrw039/2/

Comment: @Leothelion I tend to just add properties to the form-control class (in styles.css or similar) rather than removing the class completely, that way you don't lose other things you might need as part of the form-control CSS. Any styles you apply will over-write those in the default Bootstrap CSS provided you've got the files in the correct load order

Comment: but rich look and feel is missing . i need same look and feel with less width.company and comment fields are not looking good compared to email and phone filed.

Comment: @Lyall, thanx for pointing me for this but i just used custom classes in my current project and we had to remove form-control as it was giving 100% width. sorry i forget to mention that if you have requirements then you should remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your given example, you have used wrong css rules like you used `width="511px"` which is not corrcet. YOu have to use `style="width:511px;"`. you can use inline css to give your custom style to input fields. see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Leo_the_lion/Lqsrw039/6/)

We should not modify the bootstrap class style but you can if you have requirements.

like this `<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:170px;" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Company Name">`  you can override the bootstrap class.

**UPDATED** I have added custom width to input boxes and in text area you can only resize vertical.(for test)

Comment: ok thats correct..but custom style is not looking...for company and comments fields..

Comment: well i can see that they have less width. I just gave custom width to them.

Comment: im not saying about less width . im saying the borders of text box not looking like above fields

Comment: sorry but for me, they all are same.

Comment: ok thanks i had not seen ur updated answer. thanks its worked... class="form-control" style="width:170px;"

Answer (score 0):

Since you were using the bootstrap framework, in my opinion you can use grid system to responsively adjust the width

```
<div class="col-md-6"> 
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="CustomerName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Customer Name">    
     </div>
</div>
```